# how to set up localhost for smtp to send javax.emails?

Tags: smtp, localhost, jakarta-mail

Right now I am using gmail as the host, how do I make it so I can use my localhost?

I've tried to put localhost as the host, but I always get "Connection refused on localhost port 25" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to install a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) on your machine (with all the maintenance this requires). Popular ones are `sendmail` or `postfix`. Try http://superuser.com for admin-related  (not programming) questions.